# how to update vertex of a glb file

Tags: three.js

I would like to know is there any way to update the vertexes of a loaded json/glb file dinamically.

I am planning to set the positions of each vertex in x,y,z positions.

As i understand i can only access positions from a geometrybuffer but that will not have the indexing for the actual vertexes.. i would like to update the vertex like a vector positions

for example i have an array like below

```
array=[
{x:0,y:10,z,3},{x:0,y:10,z,3},{x:0,y:10,z,3}
]
```

now by using this i should be able to update each vertex of the glb/json to respective positions by same index order.

any help on this is highly appreciated

Comment: Please share code attempting to solve the problem. You've included both Unity and three.js tags here, which are very different things using different coding languages. It's difficult to know how to help, without more detail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file format used to load your model doesn't really matter, here — once it's loaded it is part of a `THREE.Scene`, which may contain some mix of Group, Object3D, Mesh, and other object types. It might have many meshes, so you'll have to "traverse" the scene hierarchy and update any meshes you need.

For example:

```js
model.traverse((object) => {
  if (object.isMesh) {
    // modify object.geometry here.
  }
});
```

To understand how to modify the mesh, see the [Mesh](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/objects/Mesh) and [BufferGeometry](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferGeometry) documentation. To update the Nth vertex position you would do something like:

```js
object.geometry.attributes.position.setXYZ(n, x, y, z);
```

Note that the `position` attribute stores positions of each vertex, and is a [BufferAttribute](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/BufferAttribute) instance.